# Print a sequence of numbers using threads without any synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to write a simple code to print numbers in sequence. Scenario is like

```
1
2
3
4
5
.. and so on
```

here is the code I have written

```
public class CounterThread implements Runnable {
    int counterNumber;

    public CounterThread(int counterNumber) {
        this.counterNumber = counterNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(this.counterNumber);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int number = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        Thread[] listOfThreads = new Thread[number];
        for(int i = 1; i <= number; i++){
            CounterThread counterThread = new CounterThread(i);
            Thread thread = new Thread(counterThread);
            thread.start();
            listOfThreads[i-1] = thread;
        }

        for(Thread thread : listOfThreads){
            thread.join();
        }
    }
}
```

I realize that this is a very bad coding practice for thread programming, but i am still at a novice level trying to understand how threads behave when synchronized and when not.
The output is jumbled which is to be expected but not what is required.
i am not sure where i am going wrong, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is there any other requirements? You are not allowed to synchronize threads - is this the only condition?

Comment: What is meant by "no synchronization"?  Ultimately you will need some sort of synchronization, but maybe what the assignment calls for is no usage of the `synchronized` keyword.

Comment: @Steyrix Yes i am not allowed to synchronize threads that is the only condition

Comment: @JoseMartinez yes you are correct, no usage of  `synchronized` keyword

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can optimize your code by writing this, it will simply make the main thread wait for the current `thread` to complete its execution.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
    CounterThread counterThread = new CounterThread(i);
    Thread thread = new Thread(counterThread);
    thread.start();
    thread.join();
}
```

However, it is a really strange piece of code. In such cases, where you are not allowed to use `synchronized` in multithreaded environment, the best you can go with is using `volatile` keyword or atomic variables. Both approaches are designed to make all the writes and reads to the variable atomic.

```
volatile int number = 1; 

...

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println(number++);
}

... 

for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
    CounterThread counterThread = new CounterThread();
    Thread thread = new Thread(counterThread);
    thread.start();
}
```

But you should note, that `volatile` does not give 100% guarantee that you will avoid race condition. Especially in this case, since `number++` will not be an atomic operation. It will be actually `number = number + 1` - one read and one write.

But with `Atomic`, incrementing will be an atomic operation and you can write something like

```
AtomicInteger number = new AtomicInteger(0);

...

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println(number.incrementAndGet());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution and providing a different approach with volatile variables, I will definitely look into this. much appreciated :)

Comment: @PrajwalKrishna you are welcome. However, you accepted another answer, which is not as informative as mine and also posted later :(

Answer (score 1):

you can just call the `join()` after the `start()` because the start of method in first loop cause it to execute and before reaching to the next loop it already did its work, so you need to call it in first loop after start to make sure its ending before starting the next one:

> the join() method which allows one thread to wait until another thread completes its execution. If t is a Thread object whose thread is currently executing, then t.join() will make sure that t is terminated before the next instruction is executed by the program.

```
public class CounterThread implements Runnable {
    int counterNumber;

    public CounterThread(int counterNumber) {
        this.counterNumber = counterNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(this.counterNumber);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int number = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);;
        for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
            CounterThread counterThread = new CounterThread(i);
            Thread thread = new Thread(counterThread);
            thread.start();
            thread.join();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Update the code, No need for that just copied from user's code

Comment: Thanks for this solution it worked like a charm :)
I wanted to know what was happening when I was joining in a different for loop ?
was the `run()` method already executed before being threads were joined ?

Comment: when you called the join in second loop the threads already started and finished their works. so I added the description of join() method, you needed to call the join after calling of start to make it sure it ends after starting the next thread

Comment: Something seems off with this solution.  Its not really being done in multithreaded... this solution uses one thread at a time.  I would imagine it would be more interesting to have the threads running at the same time.